# MS Visual Studio 2010 C# Express crashes all the time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

VS crashes every about 10 minutes usually when I'm editing text. SP1 installed. Happens on both Windows 7 + Bootcamp on Macbook Pro and Windows XP Virtual Machine hosted on Linux. OSes are up to date.

What's wrong with Visual Studio or my installation??

Comment: Doesn't belong here at all. Read FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute Visual Studio

```
Devenv.exe /Log
```

in order to get log inormations

(vcsexpress for express version)

Comment: I don't have devenv.exe . I tried vsexpress.exe /Log c:\log.txt and it didn't work

Comment: vcsexpress.exe /Log "c:\Users\windev\Desktop\log.txt"  worked for me

Comment: I'am happy for you Alex, excuse me for delay